# Cannot install bomi media player in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04

Cannot add **PPA: 'ppa:~darklin20/ubuntu/bomi'**.

> ERROR: '~darklin20' user or team does not exist.

Showing this message when suing this command:

```
 sudo add-apt-repository ppa:darklin20/bomi
```

please help me.

Comment: The PPA https://launchpad.net/~darklin20/+archive/ubuntu/bomi  supports trusty-vivid, with support being dropped before Xenial (16.04) so why expect it to work in 18.04?  I would suggest checking to see if the PPA supports your release before trying to add & use it.

Answer (score 3):

I see three moments:

1. The mentioned PPA was updated at 2015-05-20 (for Vivid Verver);
2. Bomi player's GitHub account [have releases](https://github.com/xylosper/bomi/releases) from 2015 year too;
3. You cannot simply install Bomi by deb-packages because of non-satisfied dependencies (*libva1*, *libavcodec-ffmpeg56*, etc.).

But you can install it from [other newer PPA](https://launchpad.net/~nemonein/+archive/ubuntu/bomi?field.series_filter=bionic):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nemonein/bomi
sudo apt-get install bomi
```

and use it.

Comment: can "sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nemonein/bomi" be trusted?
sorry if dope question from linux noob :)

Comment: It may be trusted as any other third-party repository.