# How can I install bomi media player in Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: ppa, 22.04, bomi

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nemonein/bomi
sudo apt-get install bomi
```

is not working.

error:

```
E: The repository 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/nemonein/bomi/ubuntu jammy Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I have already tried solutions to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1112109/cannot-install-bomi-media-player-in-ubuntu-18-04), but it does not work.

Thanks.

Comment: `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:darklin20/bomi` is not working too.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot install bomi media player in Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1112109/cannot-install-bomi-media-player-in-ubuntu-18-04)

Comment: No, actually I followed the response there but it is not working.

Comment: The PPA goes up to Ubuntu 20.04 (focal) only, something you'd have found out easily if you opened the link. Unfortunately it seems the software is abandoned. You may try to edit the software sources and. for that PPA, change "jammy" to "focal". Use at your own risk.

Comment: @ChanganAuto even then, the PPA’s key might not be valid anymore … it’s not that simple.

Comment: @Raffa Sure, hence the *... may try* and the *use at your own risk*. No guarantees it'll work whatsoever and even compiling from source may not work. Again, it's abandonware .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm the maintainer of that PPA. I made the PPA just for my personal use only. I'm not a developer.

Today, I built Bomi for Ubuntu 22.04, but haven't tested or even installed yet. I usually have used KDE Neon, which is based on Ubuntu LTS version, that's why I only built Bomi for Ubuntu LTS. Now I'm using ArchLinux.

Please try to install it from the PPA. I'm not sure it will work well. However, Bomi works fine on Archlinux, I think there'll be no problems.

Comment: It worked! Many Thanks.

Comment: @Behnamkvl what do you mean - "it worked"?) How could you install it, what command were you using?

Comment: @GreenJoffer I remember after the new build by nemonein (maintainer) I successfully installed it with the same commands in the question. I don't have an Ubuntu at the moment so I cannot test it.